# Disable optimizations for a specific file with autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools

I'm working on setting up autotools for a large code base that was once just a bash script compile and later just hand written Makefiles.

We have a set of files that require that compiler optimizations be turned off. These files are already in their own subdirectory, so they will have their own Makefile.am.

What's the proper way to drop any existing compiler optimizations and force a `-O0` flag on the compiler for these specific files?

Comment: The `COMPILE` and `LTCOMPILE` variables in `Makefile.in` seem to list `CFLAGS` as the last variable, as discussed below. Perhaps the 'cleanest' approach is a [subpackage](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Subpackages.html) where you add: `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -O0"` in `configure.ac`. It seems heavy-handed though. Please update with an answer if you find something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went with Brett Hale's comment to use [subpackages](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Subpackages.html). I was able to insert

```
: ${CFLAGS="-O0"}
```

before `AC_PROG_CC`, which sets the appropriate optimization. The other solutions do not work, since the `-g -O2` was getting added very last. You can never get another `-O` variable after it.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to remove existing optimizations: the last value of `-O` on the compiler invocation will be used, so it's good enough to just add `-O0` at the end.

This is not directly supported by automake, but there's [a trick you can use](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Per_002dObject-Flags.html) defined in the documentation.

Otherwise if you know you'll only ever invoke your makefile with GNU make you can play other tricks that are GNU make specific; you may have to disable automake warnings about non-portable content.

Comment: I can only seem to get `-O0` to appear before `-g -O2`. Where should I be adding the `-O0` flag?

Comment: You'll have to look at the way the recipe is defined.  You need to figure out what the last "flags" variable is on the command line and add it to that variable.  Unfortunately it's quite possible that the last one is `CFLAGS` which is reserved for the user... that would be a bummer.  You might have to define your own recipe.  I recommend you ask about this on the automake@gnu.org mailing list.